# Rascal createM3FromEclipseProject with huge Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, rascal

I'm completely new to [rascal](/questions/tagged/rascal). I'm currently just trying some basic things on our project and a test project.
On a test project the following works without a problem on the Rascal terminal:

```
rascal>import lang::java::m3::Core;
ok
rascal>import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
ok
rascal>myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://TestProject|);
... (output)
```

However, when I try it on our huge project, it still hasn't produced any output after more than 45 minutes of waiting. I was wondering how long this might take for huge projects.

I've checked with [the Eclipse search options](https://maxrohde.com/2011/03/30/count-lines-of-code-and-number-of-classes-in-eclipse-projects/) and we have 404,389 lines of code in our `.java` files alone, and 1,780 classes. Yes, it's a huge and complex project that's little over 10 years old.

Perhaps I should narrow it down with sub-queries instead of doing `createM3FromEclipseProject`, but I'm not 100% which yet. Is there a Rascal tutorial perhaps that only focuses on searching through Java projects (apart from the two [MeasuringJava recipes](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Basic/Hello/Hello.html#/Recipes/Metrics/MeasuringJava/MeasuringJava.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Check your profiler (VisualVM), most likely you are primarily waiting for the Garbage Collector to free up memory, then consume it, and ask for more memory again.. increasing the max memory for the JVM can greatly help (`-Xmx8G` in the eclipse.ini).